# Organizing repeating content on a single page

Tags: relations, structure, channels, singles

I have a page with a slider on it, which includes three rotating slides. In Craft, I am currently setting up each slide as an entry under a "Home Page Content" channel, and then creating an entry field for them on the home page single.

Is that the simplest/correct way to do it? Is there an alternate way that allows me to enter the number of slides and the information for each directly on the home page single?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use individual Entries within a Structure for slider / slideshow type content when I think the users will want to temporarily disable a slide and re-enable it in the future or for users that will want to schedule slides to be shown / expire at certain times.

All other times I use a Matrix Field because I have found that most people like to see all of that kind of content in one place.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Matrix Field](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/matrix-fields)! Each block in your matrix field can be a slide with whatever information you need inside. While your method will work fine, using a matrix will help keep your content organized on a single entry.